# Where can I find official resources for Canadian law on photography?

Tags: legal, canada

I know 99.9% of you are not lawyers, and I'm not really looking for advice as I have a reasonable idea of what the law allows up here. What I'm looking for was places I could go hunting to build a set of resources to stand on should I ever be confronted by someone about taking photos in a public space.

Does anyone know a good place to look for legislation or **actual** legal information about  this? Everything I find is people who are not lawyers, I'm looking for actual government published information I could possibly take to a lawyer later to build something solid I can present if I ever find myself being bullied / pressured by those who don't know what's right.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest contacting [CAPIC](http://www.capic.org) (Canadian Association of Photographers in Communication) and following up with them.

One of the main mandates of this organization is to lobby for changes in the Canadian copyright law as it pertains to photographers.

They will be able to point you in the right direction.